# Proper way to shutdown /rosout (roscore)

Tags: c++, rosout, rosnode, roscore, respawn

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a project where i start gazebo and several other rosnodes.

I want to be able to shut them all down at some point. I have a node that waits for a certain message and then shuts all other nodes down following with a self shutdown call like:

```
system("rosnode kill NAME_OF_NODE"); // shutdown other nodes
ros::shutdown();                     // shutdown this node
```

This does work for everything except the /rosout node. The /rosout node always respawns if killed with rosnode kill.
What I tried is to start a roscore in the starting programm before the other roslaunch files are executed, and then at the end, when all nodes finished cleanly I kill the roscore with kill all like:

```
system("roscore &");                 // start roscore 
...                                  // starting other nodes with roslaunch
system("killall roscore");           // kill roscore
```

But this does seem like a dirty way. Is there a better way to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263193/proper-way-to-shutdown-/rosout-(roscore)./) by [JulianR](https://answers.ros.org/users/30632/julianr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-06-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Akhilesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28821/akhilesh/) on 2017-06-06**:
Hi @Gieseltrud, try http://answers.ros.org/question/250182/terminate-ros-program/#250224

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My solution is to use a launch file to start all the relevant nodes, with the "terminator" node set to required="true". When the terminator node exits, it will trigger all of the other nodes to close if they are using things like ros::ok() to determine if they should keep running. This only works when roscore has been started by this launch file.

---

Originally posted by [Dale McConachie](https://answers.ros.org/users/30596/dale-mcconachie/) with karma: 91 on 2017-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JulianR](https://answers.ros.org/users/30632/julianr/) on 2017-06-08**:
This does work fine, There still is a red message informing about the Initiating of the shutdown, but I guess that is just how it is.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I manage ROS like this. I put all launch files inside one master "all.launch", and then I start that using the supervisor service, a simple tool for creating daemons. You can install this on Ubuntu with:

```
sudo apt-get install supervisor
```

I configure it by creating a file `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/myrobot.conf` which looks like:

```
[program:myrobot]
command=bash -c "source /usr/local/myrobot/src/ros/setup.bash; roslaunch myrobot all.launch"
directory=/usr/local/myrobot/src/ros
user=ubuntu
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor-myrobot.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor-myrobot.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=3
priority=998
stopasgroup=true
```

Then, when the system boots, it launches all your ROS nodes automatically. If you want to cleanly stop it, you'd run:

```
sudo supervisorctl stop myrobot
```

Similarly, to start it, you'd run:

```
sudo supervisorctl start myrobot
```

---

Originally posted by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) with karma: 940 on 2018-01-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1